# Pass value in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I add formula field region,fromdate,todate in report

i.e.
**UPDATED IMAGE**

[image: UPDATED IMAGE]

Also I try this another method:

```
 protected void Report_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

  data crystalReport = new data();    
 crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["region"].Text = regiondrop.SelectedValue;
        crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["fromdate"].Text = fromdate.Value;
        crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["todate"].Text = todate.Value;

BindReport(crystalReport,Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(todate.Value), regiondrop.SelectedValue);

        }
```

This show error on page:

Error

[image: error image]

> This field name is not known. Details: errorKind Error in File temp_2c6994eb-49ef-432f-bfd7-af0eb80dc7ec 4032_6896_{5E54477E-F078-41DF-BD52-AF042B96DA53}.rpt: Error in formula fromdate: '{DataTable1.StartDate}' This field name is not known. Details: errorKind

**Now this is working finally with the help of @Furtiro**

```
public  void BindReport(ReportDocument crystalReport, DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, string region)
    {

        T1 t = new T1();

        DateTime fdate = new DateTime(fromdate.Year, fromdate.Month, fromdate.Day, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime tdate = new DateTime(todate.Year, todate.Month, todate.Day, 23, 59, 59);
        List<griddataresult_Result> dsc = t.griddataresult(fdate, tdate, region).ToList();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("OwnerName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("RegNo", typeof(string));


        foreach (var c in dsc)
        {

            dt.Rows.Add(c.ID, c.OwnerName, c.RegNo, c.total_voilatio, c.MileageAccumlation, c.MaxSpeed);
        }

        crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["region"].Text = "'" + region + "'";
        crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["fromdate"].Text = "'" + fromdate + "'";
        crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["todate"].Text = "'" + todate + "'";

        crystalReport.SetDataSource(dt);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instanciate your report like an object , replace your line :

```
 ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
```

By :

```
data crystalReport = new data();
```

Here data is the name of you .rpt class.

***Update ***

You don't understand that ReportDocument is an object, your object here will be your `data` class.
So all the lines when you set `doc = crystalreport` are useless because you don't work on your crystalReport object but on other objects.

**Second update :**

I didn't see your access to the formula, you're not supposed to write the "@' in the name of your formula. My bad sorry , here's your working code :

```
protected void Report_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        data crystalReport = new data();

         crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["region"].Text = "'" + regiondrop.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";

         crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["fromdate"].Text = "'" + fromdate.Value.ToString() +"'";

         crystalReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["todate"].Text = "'"+ todate.Value.ToString() + "'";


         BindReport(crystalReport,Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(todate.Value), regiondrop.SelectedValue);

    }
```

Be careful about the dataType and parse when you write a formula in c# code, for example if you want to display some text in a formula dynamically you'll need to cast your data with quotes

Like `report.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["yourformula"].Text ="'Hello world'";` 
Dont forget the quotes, simple or double quotes will works.

Best regards,

Comment: @user6628729 Please check my updated answer and tell me if it works

Comment: check my updated code i try your code and this show same error

Comment: I saw this right before your comment, sorry , updated :)

Comment: HI thank for reply check updated image and code i try your solution and this show error Error
This field name is not known. Details: errorKind Error in File temp_2c6994eb-49ef-432f-bfd7-af0eb80dc7ec 4032_6896_{5E54477E-F078-41DF-BD52-AF042B96DA53}.rpt: Error in formula fromdate: '{DataTable1.StartDate}' This field name is not known. Details: errorKind

Comment: Actually i reproduce your code and report with a formula, and if i add the quotes like my second update suggested, it works like a charm. So i updated my answer and added some quotes .. Tell me if it works please.

Comment: i try your code and this show same error on page .. =(  .  This field name is not known. Details: errorKind Error in File temp_6b70d883-5b56-46cf-bdec-b61071023cdf 6536_6948_{9B8E1937-F98C-4285-9DB6-A72E30F7BE1F}.rpt: Error in formula fromdate: '{DataTable1.StartDate}' This field name is not known. Details: errorKind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120671/discussion-between-furtiro-and-user6628729).